# My python random number generate the same result

Tags: python, random

so i was doing this little game in python and ran across a problem. I wanted to randomize the randomNumber variable. It does change every time i run , but when i print the number it keeps on showing the same number. Example , I choose to play the game 3 times , and my game will make me enter 3 value , but the random number is the same for all 3.

**Code :**

```
import random
def guessingNumber():
    userPlayTimes = int(input('How many times you wanna play : '))
    randomNumber = random.randrange(1,10)
    userScore = 0
    for x in range(1,userPlayTimes+1):
        userGuess = int(input('Please enter your random Guess : '))
        print(userScore , randomNumber)
        if userGuess == randomNumber:
            userScore += 1
            return userScore
    print(userScore)
```

**Result :**

```
Q : How many times you wanna play : 5
Please enter your random Guess : 1
0 3 (score , randomNumber)
Q : Please enter your random Guess : 2
0 3 (score , randomNumber)
Q : Please enter your random Guess : 3
0 3 (score , randomNumber)
1 (overall score)
```

***Please don't mind if I m bad at writing because this is my first time using stackoverflow for asking quesitons.***

Comment: You randomize once and print several times. The result is the same number several times. What exactly is surprising you?

Comment: Random value is generated in  `randomNumber = random.randrange(1,10)` and that is executed only once, so tehre is only one random value.

Comment: You are generating the random number before the for loop and thus the random stays the same. Putting the `randomNumber = random.randrange(1,10)` within the for loop will generate a random number each time.

Comment: You probably dont want to return if the number is right. It means that the user score will only be displayed if you never get it right and if you get it right, you dont play the rest of the rounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move your random number selection in the inner loop.
Currently the random  number is selected, before the game starts, and will be the same for all the games.

```
for x in range(1,userPlayTimes+1):
    userGuess = int(input('Please enter your random Guess : '))
    randomNumber = random.randrange(1,10) # <-- here
    print(userScore , randomNumber)
    if userGuess == randomNumber:
        ...
```